# How to copy the contents of a directory with wildcard include path

Tags: powershell

I want to copy all of the contents of a directory, `A`, that match the pattern `'**/cat/**/*'`, and copy them to `E`, a sibling directory to `A`.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
C:
|
-- A (source folder)
|  |
|  -- B (folder)
|     |
|     -- cat (folder)
|        |
|        -- dog.txt
|
-- C (destination folder)
```

This is the powershell command I'm using from the root level (`C:`), but nothing is copied:

```
Copy-Item -Path '.\A' -Destination '.\C' -Recurse -Include '**/cat/**/*'
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

I've noted that this command:

```
Copy-Item -Path '.\A' -Destination '.\C' -Recurse
```

does succeed in recursively copying all of the contents of `A` to `C`.

Comment: So you just want to copy the contents in "cat" folder and that's it?

Comment: I want to copy all files in a “cat” folder in every child folder of A, while also copying over the child folder of A and the “cat” folder itself. In this example, Folder C would look just like folder A after the copy. If folder A also had children that had no “cat” folder, they wouldnt appear in C. If A  had children that had contained a “cat” folder and other items, only the “cat” folder and it’s contents would be copied under those children in C

Comment: I'm sorry but, can you rephrase that? Doesn't make sense to me. Sorry, I'm just a little slow(:

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Sure, no problem. I don't know what the child folders of `A` will be called, but I want to copy any grandchildren folders of `A` titled `"cat"`, along with all of those grandchildren's contents. I want these selected grandchildren folders to be copied over along with their parent folders (which are child folders of `A`)

Comment: Put another way, I want to copy all child folders of `A` that themselves have a child folder called `"cat"`. I don't want to copy any other child folders of `A` and I don't want to copy any other grandchildren of `A` but the `"cat"` folders and their contents

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you'd like to find this Directory with the name of "*cat*", that's nested in the Directory named "*A*", and copy all the file/folder contents in it to Directory "*C*"

```
$CatFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path '.\A' -Filter "cat" -Directory -Recurse 
Get-ChildItem -Path $CatFolder.FullName -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination '.\C' -Recurse
```

Try this.

Comment: There may be more than one second-level/grandchild directory named "cat"

Comment: I want to copy all of those, along with their parent folder

Comment: just the parent folder name, or contents within the parent folder as well?

Comment: meaning: "C:\folder1\cat","C:\Folder2\cat\". So, copy the just the folder name with the contents of just the cat folder, or all the contents inside the parent folder and not JUST cat